# Select box event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 select boxes. First I choose an item from Item 1. If I check the `checkbox` from item 2, the value of `select box` from item 2 should be the same as `select box` from item 1, but it does not work. What's wrong?

Here is my code:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="item1">
        <option id=1>Banana</option>
        <option id=2>Apple</option>
        <option id=3>Phineapple</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <th>Item 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
      <select id="item2">
        <option id=1>Banana</option>
        <option id=2>Apple</option>
        <option id=3>Phineapple</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: So what issue did you faced? Also, `id` must be unique across the entire document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: If you want use `Id's` for option try to add unique `Id's`, in your case it is duplicated, also `Id's` should be in string like `<option id="1">Banana</option>`, you are passing numbers directly. If possible don't use numbers for `Id's`**

You can do this in 2 ways,

**Scenario 1:**

You have two `select` box and a `checkbox`. On `first select` box change you need to check if `checkbox` is checked or not, if checkbox is checked then copy the `select box value` to another like below,

```
$("#item1").on('change',function(){

  if($("#chk").is(":checked")){
    $("#item2").val($(this).val());
  }
})
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/kajarazowu/edit?html,js,console,output)

**Scenario 2:**

If you want to copy `first select box value` to another on the base of `checkbox` status, you can do like this,

```
$('#chk').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#item2').val($('#item1').val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple here. Try this :

```js
$('#chk').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#item2').val($('#item1').val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="item1">
        <option id=1>Banana</option>
        <option id=2>Apple</option>
        <option id=3>Phineapple</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <th>Item 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
      <select id="item2">
        <option id=1>Banana</option>
        <option id=2>Apple</option>
        <option id=3>Phineapple</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify that you were using Jquery, here is a vainilla Javascript solution:

```js
let oneSelect = document.getElementById('oneSelect');
let anotherSelect = document.getElementById('anotherSelect');

function checkTheOtherOne(event) {
  let isChecked = event.target.checked;
  if (isChecked && getOneSelectValue() != getAnotherSelectValue()) {
      for (let i = 0; i < anotherSelect.childNodes.length; i++) {
          const option = anotherSelect.childNodes[i];
          if (option.value === getOneSelectValue()) {
              option.selected = true;
              break;
          }
      }
  }

  function getOneSelectValue() {
      return oneSelect.value;
  }

  function getAnotherSelectValue() {
      return anotherSelect.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>
    One select:
    <select id="oneSelect">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</label>


<label>
    <input value="true" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" oninput="checkTheOtherOne(event)">
</label>


<label>
    Another select:
    <select id="anotherSelect">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

As the first comment has pointed out, remember that the `id` in a document must be unique.

Comment: Nice answer, except you missed the part about the checkbox. (I smoothed out the question's language so it might be clearer now.)

Comment: There, I made a quick fix to it. Now it should do what you want.